# Seeking Starbucks in Vienna very near to public transportation

Tags: public-transport, work, austria, vienna, cafes

I have searched Google maps and found none, but I saw that in my city many bus stops are not marked, so I hoped you could help me. Less than 300m from public transportation would be great.

I am disabled and moving to Vienna.

Comment: You could have a look at the [store locator](http://en.starbucks.at/store-locator/search/location/Vienna%2C%20Austria) on their website. A first cursory look at it reveals at least a couple of outlets at or near railway/subway station (Hauptbahnhof, Westbahnhof, Karlsplatz, the former two even seem to be inside the railway station).

Comment: You're in Vienna, one of the great coffee cities.  I realise Starbucks is great and all, but Vienna is famous for its coffee. Try another cafe if you can!

Comment: @MarkMayo Very true and I will, with my family. But to work I will go to Starbucks. It has wifi and allows me to refill and bring my own water. And I am a bit  poor, so I like paying 2,50 and sitting there for hours (blush)

Comment: As regards sitting for hours over a single coffee: Viennese coffee houses already implemented this "feature" a century before Starbucks (see e.g. [Wikipedia's summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viennese_coffee_house#Viennese_coffee_house_culture)). Their generous provision of newspapers and journals might also count as the contemporary equivalent of free wifi (these days, they tend to provide actual wifi as well). On the other hand Starbucks may work out cheaper overall, because the cake selection can be very hard to resist in a traditional café :-).

Comment: @MarkMayo: People who actually go there for the coffee as such might find some redeeming points, but compared to any Viennese-style confectionery-café, I have always found Starbuck's tiny selection of cake and muffins rather disappointing. Thus, I second your suggestion to "try another café".

Comment: _"I am… moving to Vienna"_ — Doesn't that make this a question for [expats.se] (if it's an appropriate question at all)?

Comment: @200_success Not if she's moving from elsewhere in Vienna. Anyway, Expatriates would require proof that similar non-expat locals wouldn't also visit Starbucks (and consequently, has almost nothing but legal questions about paperwork).  Everyone's happy with this question, it'd apply equally to disabled visitors as residents, and commuting questions were just ruled on-topic. It's fine, let it be :-)

Comment: @MarkMayo I made a question especially for traditional coffee houses, see here please http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61994/seeking-traditional-coffeehouse-in-vienna-extremely-close-to-public-transporta

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can search for stores on the Starbucks site, here are the [results for Vienna, Austria](http://www.starbucks.com/store-locator/search/location/Vienna%2C%20Austria). There are many stores and many are near U-Bahn stations and/or tram and bus stops.

For example [this store](http://www.starbucks.com/store-locator/search/location/vienna%2C%20austria/detail/172) is right beside [Wien Mitte Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_Mitte_railway_station) and also even closer to a local tram stop, here's a Google Maps shot:

[image]

and a close up showing the tram stop:

[image]

But there are plenty others that may be more convenient for you.

**AND**, although I'm a Starbucks fan myself, I'll point out that Vienna has plenty of other coffee shops that and excellent public transport. So you'll be able to find plenty of choices ...

Comment: Thank you, it appears bus stops within the visible area become invisible, when the zoom is too high. So I could find none.

Comment: @Ludi You really need to zoom in a lot with Google maps to get the full picture of what's in the area.

Comment: I started going to the Schottengasse. It is very close to the station Schottentor and reachable with a lot of trams.

Answer (score 21):

I notice in the comments that you're looking for somewhere to sit and work.

Apparently, Vienna has a very high concentration of **co-working spaces** purpose-designed for the sort of thing you're looking to do. From [this article](http://www.deskmag.com/en/coworking-spaces-in-vienna-austria-505):

> Move over coffee shops! The Viennese have found a better place to work, connect, and stay warm: Austria may be small, but ...[has]... one the highest number of coworking spaces per capita in the world, many of them are located in the country’s capital.

It lists 12 coworking space initiatives (so at least one is likely to be accessible), three of which are part of a network called [Konnex](http://www.konnex.cc/) which also offers members:

> ...an additional range of local services, such as car sharing or “Gemüsekistl” (fresh-delivered vegetables)

Some of these services might be useful to a disabled newcomer to a city, and initiatives like co-working spaces of like-minded pro-community people like this are likely to be a better way to make useful contacts and friends in a new city than Starbucks.

In my experience, the kind of people who join and run initiatives like this will be very enthusiastic about helping a newcomer with specific needs to settle and be productive in their city.